# Jetty 11. Secure Connection Failed with godaddy certificate

Tags: java, ssl, jetty

I'm trying to use a Godaddy certificate to create a secure http connection.

First I tested my code with a self signed certificate and work fine, but when I try to use the certificate from godaddy I have a `SSL_ERROR_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ALERT` on firefox and a `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` in Chrome. No exception. No error log. No messages.

```
Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection to servername.com:8443. SSL peer was unable to negotiate an acceptable set of security parameters.

Error code: SSL_ERROR_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ALERT

    The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
    Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.
```

The debug log before the exception:

```
[server-33] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool  - Runner started for QueuedThreadPool[server]@33e5ccce{STARTED,8<=12<=200,i=0,r=-1,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@627551fb{s=1/16,p=0}]
[server-22] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.SocketChannelEndPoint  - Key interests updated 1 -> 0 on SocketChannelEndPoint@2e9703df{l=/127.0.1.1:8443,r=/127.0.0.1:41822,OPEN,fill=FI,flush=-,to=4/30000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->SslConnection@1008464{NOT_HANDSHAKING,eio=-1/-1,di=-1,fill=INTERESTED,flush=IDLE}~>DecryptedEndPoint@38876f9b{l=/127.0.1.1:8443,r=/127.0.0.1:41822,OPEN,fill=FI,flush=-,to=4/30000}=>HttpConnection@1ae6359c[p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@c862f5c{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@525f5018{s=HttpChannelState@3f48616b{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=0,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0}
[server-22] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector  - Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@3fc1893b waiting with 1 keys
[server-33] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool  - run SocketChannelEndPoint@2e9703df{l=/127.0.1.1:8443,r=/127.0.0.1:41822,OPEN,fill=FI,flush=-,to=4/30000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->SslConnection@1008464{NOT_HANDSHAKING,eio=-1/-1,di=-1,fill=INTERESTED,flush=IDLE}~>DecryptedEndPoint@38876f9b{l=/127.0.1.1:8443,r=/127.0.0.1:41822,OPEN,fill=FI,flush=-,to=5/30000}=>HttpConnection@1ae6359c[p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@c862f5c{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@525f5018{s=HttpChannelState@3f48616b{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=0,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0}:runFillable:BLOCKING in QueuedThreadPool[server]@33e5ccce{STARTED,8<=12<=200,i=0,r=-1,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@627551fb{s=1/16,p=0}]
[server-33] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest  - fillable FillInterest@6d28095a{SSLC.NBReadCB@1008464{SslConnection@1008464::SocketChannelEndPoint@2e9703df{l=/127.0.1.1:8443,r=/127.0.0.1:41822,OPEN,fill=FI,flush=-,to=4/30000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->SslConnection@1008464{NOT_HANDSHAKING,eio=-1/-1,di=-1,fill=INTERESTED,flush=IDLE}~>DecryptedEndPoint@38876f9b{l=/127.0.1.1:8443,r=/127.0.0.1:41822,OPEN,fill=FI,flush=-,to=5/30000}=>HttpConnection@1ae6359c[p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@c862f5c{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@525f5018{s=HttpChannelState@3f48616b{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=0,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0}}}
[server-33] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection  - >c.onFillable SslConnection@1008464::SocketChannelEndPoint@2e9703df{l=/127.0.1.1:8443,r=/127.0.0.1:41822,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=5/30000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->SslConnection@1008464{NOT_HANDSHAKING,eio=-1/-1,di=-1,fill=INTERESTED,flush=IDLE}~>DecryptedEndPoint@38876f9b{l=/127.0.1.1:8443,r=/127.0.0.1:41822,OPEN,fill=FI,flush=-,to=5/30000}=>HttpConnection@1ae6359c[p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@c862f5c{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@525f5018{s=HttpChannelState@3f48616b{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=0,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0}
[server-33] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection  - onFillable SslConnection@1008464::SocketChannelEndPoint@2e9703df{l=/127.0.1.1:8443,r=/127.0.0.1:41822,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=5/30000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->SslConnection@1008464{NOT_HANDSHAKING,eio=-1/-1,di=-1,fill=INTERESTED,flush=IDLE}~>DecryptedEndPoint@38876f9b{l=/127.0.1.1:8443,r=/127.0.0.1:41822,OPEN,fill=FI,flush=-,to=6/30000}=>HttpConnection@1ae6359c[p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@c862f5c{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@525f5018{s=HttpChannelState@3f48616b{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=0,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0}
[server-33] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest  - fillable FillInterest@66f8bebc{AC.ReadCB@1ae6359c{HttpConnection@1ae6359c::DecryptedEndPoint@38876f9b{l=/127.0.1.1:8443,r=/127.0.0.1:41822,OPEN,fill=FI,flush=-,to=6/30000}}}
[server-33] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection  - HttpConnection@1ae6359c::DecryptedEndPoint@38876f9b{l=/127.0.1.1:8443,r=/127.0.0.1:41822,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=6/30000} onFillable enter HttpChannelState@3f48616b{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0} null
[server-33] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection  - >fill SslConnection@1008464::SocketChannelEndPoint@2e9703df{l=/127.0.1.1:8443,r=/127.0.0.1:41822,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=5/30000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->SslConnection@1008464{NOT_HANDSHAKING,eio=-1/-1,di=-1,fill=IDLE,flush=IDLE}~>DecryptedEndPoint@38876f9b{l=/127.0.1.1:8443,r=/127.0.0.1:41822,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=6/30000}=>HttpConnection@1ae6359c[p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@c862f5c{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@525f5018{s=HttpChannelState@3f48616b{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=0,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0}
[server-33] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection  - fill NOT_HANDSHAKING
[server-33] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.SocketChannelEndPoint  - filled 517 HeapByteBuffer@7a6e94fa[p=0,l=517,c=17408,r=517]={<<<\x16\x03\x01\x02\x00\x01\x00\x01\xFc\x03\x03\xCc\xB0>\x1f8"\xCf\xD6-^m\x04\xC0\xC3...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00>>>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00}
[server-33] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection  - net filled=517
[server-33] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection  - fill starting handshake SslConnection@1008464::SocketChannelEndPoint@2e9703df{l=/127.0.1.1:8443,r=/127.0.0.1:41822,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=0/30000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->SslConnection@1008464{NOT_HANDSHAKING,eio=517/-1,di=-1,fill=IDLE,flush=IDLE}~>DecryptedEndPoint@38876f9b{l=/127.0.1.1:8443,r=/127.0.0.1:41822,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=7/30000}=>HttpConnection@1ae6359c[p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@c862f5c{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@525f5018{s=HttpChannelState@3f48616b{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=0,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0}
[server-33] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection  - unwrap net_filled=517 Status = OK HandshakeStatus = NEED_TASK bytesConsumed = 517 bytesProduced = 0 encryptedBuffer=[p=517,l=517,c=17408,r=0] unwrapBuffer=DirectByteBuffer@73daf2e[p=0,l=0,c=17408,r=0]={<<<>>>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00} appBuffer=DirectByteBuffer@73daf2e[p=0,l=0,c=17408,r=0]={<<<>>>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00}
[server-33] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection  - fill NEED_TASK
[server-33] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory  - SNI matching for type=host_name (0), value=hayquecomer.com
[server-33] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory  - SNI host name hayquecomer.com
[server-33] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SniX509ExtendedKeyManager  - Chose explicit alias null/EC on sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl@3dd0a710
[server-33] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SniX509ExtendedKeyManager  - Chose explicit alias null/EC on sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl@3dd0a710
[server-33] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SniX509ExtendedKeyManager  - Chose explicit alias null/EC on sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl@3dd0a710
[server-33] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SniX509ExtendedKeyManager  - Chose explicit alias null/RSA on sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl@3dd0a710
[server-33] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SniX509ExtendedKeyManager  - Chose explicit alias null/RSA on sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl@3dd0a710
[server-33] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SniX509ExtendedKeyManager  - Chose explicit alias null/RSA on sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl@3dd0a710
[server-33] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SniX509ExtendedKeyManager  - Chose explicit alias null/RSA on sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl@3dd0a710
[server-33] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SniX509ExtendedKeyManager  - Chose explicit alias null/RSA on sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl@3dd0a710
[server-33] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SniX509ExtendedKeyManager  - Chose explicit alias null/RSA on sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl@3dd0a710
[server-33] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SniX509ExtendedKeyManager  - Chose explicit alias null/EC on sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl@3dd0a710
[server-33] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SniX509ExtendedKeyManager  - Chose explicit alias null/RSA on sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl@3dd0a710
[server-33] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection  - fill NEED_WRAP
[server-33] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection  - >flush SslConnection@1008464::SocketChannelEndPoint@2e9703df{l=/127.0.1.1:8443,r=/127.0.0.1:41822,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=31/30000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->SslConnection@1008464{NEED_WRAP,eio=0/-1,di=-1,fill=IDLE,flush=IDLE}~>DecryptedEndPoint@38876f9b{l=/127.0.1.1:8443,r=/127.0.0.1:41822,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=39/30000}=>HttpConnection@1ae6359c[p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@c862f5c{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@525f5018{s=HttpChannelState@3f48616b{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=0,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0}
[server-33] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection  - flush b[0]=HeapByteBuffer@3335b1d9[p=0,l=0,c=0,r=0]={<<<>>>}
[server-33] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection  - flush NEED_WRAP
[server-33] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection  - DecryptedEndPoint@38876f9b{l=/127.0.1.1:8443,r=/127.0.0.1:41822,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=39/30000} stored flush exception
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No available authentication scheme
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:311)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:267)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:258)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateProducer.onProduceCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:955)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateProducer.produce(CertificateMessage.java:944)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.produce(SSLHandshake.java:440)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$T13ClientHelloConsumer.goServerHello(ClientHello.java:1252)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$T13ClientHelloConsumer.consume(ClientHello.java:1188)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.onClientHello(ClientHello.java:851)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.consume(ClientHello.java:812)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1260)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1247)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1192)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.fill(SslConnection.java:627)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.fillRequestBuffer(HttpConnection.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.onFillable(SslConnection.java:528)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:377)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$2.succeeded(SslConnection.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SocketChannelEndPoint$1.run(SocketChannelEndPoint.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:894)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1038)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

I created the keystore using the follow comands:

```sh
keytool -import -alias intermediate -trustcacerts -file gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt -keystore main.keystore -storetype jks
keytool -import -alias main -trustcacerts -file 4331e701f4d1b69.crt -keystore main.keystore
```

And in a desperate moment also tried with:

```sh
keytool -import -alias main -trustcacerts -file 4331e701f4d1b69.pem -keystore main.keystore
```

and

```sh
openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl -certfile 4331e701f4d1b69.crt -out 4331e701f4d1b69.p7b -certfile gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
keytool -import -alias main -trustcacerts -file 4331e701f4d1b69.p7b -keystore main.keystore
```

The command:

```sh
keytool -list -v -keystore main.keystore
```

The command show two keys:

```sh
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 2 entries

Alias name: intermediate
Creation date: May 26, 2021
Entry type: trustedCertEntry
...
Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit RSA key
Version: 3

Extensions: 
...
Alias name: main
Creation date: May 26, 2021
Entry type: trustedCertEntry
...
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit RSA key
Version: 3

Extensions: 
...
```

And my code work with the self signed certificate. I change only the filename:

```java
  public void start() throws ServerException, FileNotFoundException {
    QueuedThreadPool threadPool = new QueuedThreadPool();
    threadPool.setName("server");
    server = new Server(threadPool);
    HttpConfiguration httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();
    httpConfig.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer(false));
    HttpConnectionFactory http11 = new HttpConnectionFactory(httpConfig);
    SslContextFactory.Server sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory.Server();
    File file = new File("/home/esteban/.../ssl/main.keystore");
    if (!file.exists()) {
      throw new FileNotFoundException(file.toString());
    }

    sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePath(file.toString());
    sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("password");

    SslConnectionFactory tls = new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory, http11.getProtocol());
    ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server, tls, http11);
    connector.setPort(8443);
    server.addConnector(connector);
    server.setHandler(new AbstractHandler() {
      @Override
      public void handle(String target, Request jettyRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.getWriter().print("nada");
        jettyRequest.setHandled(true);
        response.setStatus(200);
        response.setHeader("X-URL", request.getRequestURI());
        response.setHeader("X-HOST", request.getServerName());
      }
    });

    try {
      server.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new ServerException(e);
    }
  }
```

I did try in my computer using `/etc/hosts` in order to have the right hostname and on the remote server with the same result.

I don't have more ideas. I need some fresh.

Comment: Your keystore contains no key pairs. Both your CA certificates and your own have been imported as trusted CA certificates. You need to import your own certificate *without* the `-trustcacerts` option, and using the same alias with which you created the original keypair and CSR. Then the certificate will be associated with the keypair and it will show up as a key entry, not a certificate entry.

Comment: I already created a self signed certificate and it works fine. My problem is with the Godaddy certificate. I did not create the certificate, Godaddy gave it to me and don't have any alias for it. I just have a zip from Godaddy with: xxx.pem, xxx.crt, and gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt, a "GoDaddy Certificate Bundles - G2 With Cross to G1, includes Root"

Comment: You created the certificate how? First thin you had to do was create a key pair and then a CSR. Where is the keypair? You created the CSR how?